# How to extract text and user names from a chat in using javascript console?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web-scraping

After entering a page and pressing control + shift + k Iam trying to write an JavaScript extraction code that extracts the date, username, and text. In the console There are too many to copy and paste and I want to extract this to a txt file. This currently lays in body of the html hidden.
Iam looking for output like this:

```
little ricky 2021-06-12T23:58:55.522Z Enjoy. I was just there.
```

I tried:

```
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("header-23xsNx").text)
```

which return undefined.

Heres the html username and date Iam looking for:

```
<h2 class="header-23xsNx"><span class="headerText-3Uvj1Y"><span class="username-1A8OIy desaturateUserColors-1gar-1 clickable-1bVtEA" 
aria-controls="popout_509" aria-expanded="false" style="color: rgb(241, 196, 15);" role="button" tabindex="0">
little ricky</span></span><span class="timestamp-3ZCmNB timestampInline-yHQ6fX">
<time aria-label="Today at 6:58 PM" datetime="2021-06-12T23:58:55.522Z">
<i class="separator-2nZzUB" aria-hidden="true"> — 
</i>Today at 6:58 PM</time></span></h2>
```

Heres where the text portion is:

```
<div class="markup-2BOw-j messageContent-2qWWxC">Enjoy. I was just there.</div>
```

Comment: Where is the text portion in the first code sample?

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl added above but received an undefined.

Comment: @Spectric for a js pro this is easy. I dont know how to grab the html tag. So how farther can I write this out.

Comment: @JeanS My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var constructed = document.querySelector('.username-1A8OIy').innerText+' '+document.querySelector('time').getAttribute('datetime')+' '+document.querySelector('.messageContent-2qWWxC').innerText;
console.log(constructed);
```

```html
<h2 class="header-23xsNx"><span class="headerText-3Uvj1Y"><span class="username-1A8OIy desaturateUserColors-1gar-1 clickable-1bVtEA" 
aria-controls="popout_509" aria-expanded="false" style="color: rgb(241, 196, 15);" role="button" tabindex="0">
little ricky</span></span><span class="timestamp-3ZCmNB timestampInline-yHQ6fX">
<time aria-label="Today at 6:58 PM" datetime="2021-06-12T23:58:55.522Z">
<i class="separator-2nZzUB" aria-hidden="true"> — 
</i>Today at 6:58 PM</time></span></h2>
<div class="markup-2BOw-j messageContent-2qWWxC">Enjoy. I was just there.</div>
```

Comment: This works. do I place a for loop to get all values cause currently only one username, date, text is outputed. When I use .querySelectorAll I get an undefined.

Comment: @JeanS Yes, although the class names indicate that they are probably randomly generated, so the code probably won't work.

Comment: it looks like all usernames are using the same tag. When I tried using SelectorAll I receive an undefined error. is there a specific part I need to loop over.